# Is there a way to add an external term to the BEKK-GARCH process in R?

Tags: r

BEKK-GARCH model with external term

I tried to use the BEKK-GARCH process with an external term, but I couldn't find any built-in function which takes into account the external term. Does anyone give me any idea about this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.